# CLT for random variables with varying distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

The following is *not* a homework problem. Here it is:

Suppose $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that
$$
P(X_k=1)=P(X_k=-1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2k^2}
$$

$$
P(X_k=k)=P(X_k=-k)=\frac{1}{2k^2}.
$$
Find the limiting distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$.

Now, I am guessing that the given probabilities are for $k\geq 2$, since $k=1$ would yield an inconsistent definition. Furthermore, I am assuming the case $k=1$ corresponds to only the second line.

The first sign of trouble comes from the fact that these random variables are not identically distributed (otherwise, we could just use CLT). One thing I noticed is that $\mathbb{E}(X_k)=0$ for each $k$. Also, it appears as though the limit of the sequence is a random variable $X$ with $P(X=1)=P(X=-1)=\frac{1}{2} \hspace{2mm}$  (not that this result is necessarily of much help).

I'd very much appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Another thing that may or may not help: Borel-Cantelli lemma tells me that the event that $X_k=k$ or $X_k=-k$ does not occur infinitely often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $Y_k=\mathrm{sgn}(X_k)$, then $(Y_k)$ is a centered i.i.d. Bernoulli sequence hence, by the most usual CLT, $T_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable $T$. By Borel-Cantelli lemma, the random set $\{n\geqslant1\mid X_n\ne Y_n\}$ is almost surely finite hence there exists some almost surely finite random variable $Z$ such that $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k-\sum\limits_{k=1}^nY_k\right|\leqslant Z$ for every $n$. In particular $R_n-T_n\to0$ almost surely, where $R_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k$.

Now it is a general fact that if $T_n\to T$ in distribution and if $R_n-T_n\to0$ almost surely then $R_n\to T$ in distribution. Thus, CLT holds for $(X_n)$ as well.

Comment: @nrpeterson No problem at all since convergence in distribution does not require the convergence of moments. For example, $X_n\to X$ in distribution where $X$ is standard Bernoulli hence $\mathrm{var}(X)=1$ although $\mathrm{var}(X_n)=2-\frac1{n^2}\to2\ne1$. (And congrats for your PhD!)

Comment: Woops, you're right.  My apologies.  Off to find coffee!

Comment: Very nice! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The limiting distribution is **normal**.

You're correct that you can't use the classical CLT here. But you **can** use the Lindeberg CLT. That version of the theorem does not require identically distributed random variables, provided that certain conditions are met.

To use this theorem, you have to set up your problem using a triangular array. Basically, in the first row of the array you will have just $X_1$. In the second row, you'll have $X_1, X_2$. In the third row, $X_1, X_2, X_3$, and so on. Variables are repeated across rows, so any two rows contain non-independent variables. However, *within* each row, all the variables are independent, which is what the theorem requires.

The only other thing you need to check is the Lindeberg condition. This might seem tricky at first, but if you calculate the variances of a handful of $X_k$'s, you'll find that as $k \to \infty$, Var$(X_k) \to 2$, and it never exceeds 2. A little more thinking will give you the Lindeberg condition easily.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose $\{X_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of independent random
variables such that $$ P(X_k=1)=P(X_k=-1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2k^2}
$$

$$ P(X_k=k)=P(X_k=-k)=\frac{1}{2k^2}. $$ Find the limiting distribution of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k$.
The characteristic function of $X_k$ is
$$\phi_k(\xi)=(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2k^2})e^{i\xi}+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2k^2})e^{-i\xi}+\frac{1}{2k^2}e^{ik\xi}+\frac{1}{2k^2}e^{-ik\xi}$$
$$=(1-\frac{1}{k^2})\cos \xi +\frac{1}{k^2}\cos k\xi = \cos \xi +\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos k\xi-\cos\xi)$$
Then the characteristic function of $X_k/\sqrt{n}$ is
$$Ee^{i\xi X_k/\sqrt{n}}=\cos \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}} +\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos \frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}})$$
and
$$Ee^{i\xi(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)/\sqrt{n}}=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\cos \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}} +\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos \frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}})\right)$$
$$=\exp\left[\log \sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-(1-\cos \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos
\frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}}))\right)\right]$$
Then
$$\log \sum_{k=1}^n\left(1-(1-\cos \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos
\frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}}))\right)$$
$$\sim -\sum_{k=1}^n(1-\cos \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos \frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}}))$$
$$\sim -\sum_{k=1}^n(1-\cos \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}})+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos \frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}})=S_1+S_2$$
For $S_1$ we have
$$S_1=-n(1-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}})=-2n
\sin^2\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}}=-2n\frac{\sin^2\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{\xi^2}{n}}\times\frac{\xi^2}{n}
\to -2\xi^2 , \ \ n \to \infty.$$
$$S_2=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}(\cos
\frac{k\xi}{\sqrt{n}}-\cos\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{n}})=-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\sin\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}\sin\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
$$=-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{(k^2-1)\xi^2}{n}\frac{\sin\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}\frac{\sin\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}} }$$
$$=-2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\xi^2}{n}\frac{\sin\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}\frac{\sin\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}} }+
2\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}\frac{\xi^2}{n}\frac{\sin\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(k+1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}\frac{\sin\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{(k-1)\xi}{2\sqrt{n}} }$$
$$=S_{21}+S_{22}.$$

Now it is clear that $S_{21} \to -2\xi^2$ and $S_{22} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
Therefore
$$Ee^{i\xi(\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)/\sqrt{n}} \to e^{-4\xi^2}, \ \ n \to \infty.$$
This is the characteristic function of r.v. $X=2Z \sim N(0,4)$.

Comment: Several steps are problematic here: 1. The first $\sim$ refers probably to the *logarithm* of the expectation written above, not to the expectation itself. 2. One cannot apply the logarithm function to complex numbers with no restriction. 3. The rest which the equivalent neglects should be controlled. 4. The step leading to $S_{21}\to-2\xi^2$ is too sketchy (each ratio with a sine goes to $1$ but there are $n\to\infty$ ratios hence some uniform control is needed here). 5. The characteristic function you found yields N(0,8), not N(0,4). 6. The true limiting distribution is N(0,1).

Comment: I think that everything is OK.

Comment: Really? Aren't you worried that the variance you find is off (not to mention my points 2.-3.-4.-5.)?

Comment: I do not worry about anythihg,at all. On the other hand I am in great respect with you, by this reason I will check my calculation tomorrow.